# How to justify why a negative sign reflects a parabola over its vertex (x value)

Tags: polynomials

Sorry if this is a really dumb question but I have to justify the above and just cannot think of how to.

Comment: What do you mean by turning point? Actually its flipped about x axis

Comment: It is not, I think the asker of the question means the vertex.

Comment: Did you mean to ask why the parabolas $ax^2+bx+c$ and $-ax^2+bx+c$ 'open up' in the opposite directions?

Comment: Why do you “have” to justify this? It seems pretty intuitive to me. Also related: the vertex form of a parabola: $y=a(x-h)^2+k$.

Answer (score 1):

Graph $x^2$ and $-x^2$ side by side.

Comment: I have to justify why the negative sign does this

Comment: You can justify it with a graph, $-x^2$ is the same graph as $x^2$ when graphed, except reflected over the vertex of $x^2$, coordinates $(0,0)$ @HarryTong

Answer (score 1):

Because if a parabola, say $f(x)$, has absolute maximum at point $x_0$, then $-f(x)$ should have absolute minimum at $x_0$ and vice versa. But when we multiply $f(x)$ by $(-1)$, we don't flip the parabola over it's turning point. We are taking the symmetry of it with respect to the $x-$axis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

*From the way the question has been posed, I assume you are talking about functions. Otherwise, leave a comment so as to make the appropriate edits.*

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that its graph is a parabola. Then, by definition, its graph is the set:
$$G(f):=\{(x,f(x))|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
Now, the graph of $-f$ is the set:
$$G(-f)=\{(x,-f(x))|x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
Can you continue now?